# Compare dates from string without time

Tags: android

I need to compare whether a date is after another date. For example, today is 12 January 2020. First, I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date pDate = dateFormat.parse("12/01/2020");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            if (currentDate.after(pDate)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Although both date are the same, I got the toast "after". Then I tried this:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
        if (currentDate.after(currentDate)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "same day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This time I got the toast "same day". Lastly I changed to date to 13/01/2020:

```
Date pDate = dateFormat.parse("13/01/2020");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            if (currentDate.after(pDate)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "before", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

And I got the toast "before". The method seems working, but why the first code returned "after" even both date are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by converting the today time to 00:00:00

```
private Date getZeroTimeDate(Date date) {
        Date res;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        res = calendar.getTime();

        return res;
    }
```

Then

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date pDate = dateFormat.parse("12/01/2020");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            if (getZeroTimeDate(currentDate).after(pDate)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your first scenario works as expected. The date that you compare with current date is really before of current date. Let me explain:

`pDate` **contains** Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 where time part is **00:00:00**

`currentDate` **contains** Sun Jan 12 17:05:19 where time part is **17:05:19**

So, your `currentDate` always after of your `pDate`.

***To overcome this you have to compare date part only.***

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date pDate = dateFormat.parse("12/01/2020");
Date currentDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

if (currentDate.after(pDate)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "after", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look at date class source code [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Date-source.html), it shows that they use the number of milliseconds for each dates. you are ignoring the hours, minutes and seconds values, and that's why you got the first result